# GNUPLOT on Mac "x11 aborted"

Tags: gnuplot, homebrew

To install `gnuplot` with `x11`, I used the following command:

```
brew install gnuplot --with-x11
```

I am running OS X EL Capitan Version 10.11.6. When I run gnuplot, I obtain:

```
    G N U P L O T   Version 5.0 patchlevel 5    last modified 2016-10-02

    Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2016  Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

    gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info   faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"   immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

Terminal type set to 'unknown'
```

I then tried to plot something simple like sin(x) and I get the error

```
gnuplot: unable to open display ''
gnuplot: X11 aborted.
```

Any advice?

Comment: Did you install XQuartz? Does x11 show up when you just type in `set term`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you haven't yet, you have to type the command

```
set term x11
```

this is fundamental, because without having set a `term` you can't have an output. 
Then, if it's still not working, try uninstalling **gnuplot** and reinstall with another terminal, e.g. the `qt` terminal (which is good also because if you have a 3D plot you can interact with it), by using the command

```
 brew uninstall gnuplot
 brew install gnuplot --with-qt
```

Alternatively, if you really need `x11` as terminal you can have a look [here on AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103814/cant-plot-with-gnuplot-on-my-mac) (seem someone has already had a similar issue).

Also, typing `set term` could be helpful and give you the entire list of gnuplot terminal pre-installed, and remember, if you have a question check before the GNUPLOT guide, which is accessible with the command `help "ANYTHING_INSIDE_GNUPLOT"`, in your case:

```
help term
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've `XQuartz` installed when installing with `--with-x11`.

Otherwise try reinstalling `gnuplot` with QT, e.g.

```
brew reinstall gnuplot --with-qt
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to logout and login again after installing XQuartz before `set term x11` worked.